# Where is setDoNotUseCategoryId() declared and what does it mean?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, collection, product-relations

While getting related products, cross sells and upsells and collections, the function `setDoNotUseCategoryId()` is used.

Where is it declared and can you explain the usage?

```
    foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
       // var_dump($product);exit;
        $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

It is a "magic setter", so it is not declared anywhere but automatically translates to `setData('do_not_use_category_id', true)`. To find its usages, look for the corresponding magic getter `getDoNotUseCategoryId()`.

You will find it in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::_getCategoryIdForUrl()`

```
/**
 * Check product category
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return int|null
 */
protected function _getCategoryIdForUrl($product, $params)
{
    if (isset($params['_ignore_category'])) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $product->getCategoryId() && !$product->getDoNotUseCategoryId()
            ? $product->getCategoryId() : null;
    }
}
```

That means, the product category will be ignored for the URL, and it will always be something like `http://example.com/product.html` and not `http://example.com/category/product.html`

Answer (score 5):

You can reach the product by at least 2 different urls if the product is in a category.
Either by direct url : `product.html`.
Either by category url: `category/subcategory/product.html`.
The method call `setDoNotUseCategoryId` makes Magento retrieve the product url without the `category/subcategory` path.

The method does not exist.
It is called magically via `__call`.
It is equivalent to `$product->setData('do_not_use_category_id', true)`.

Later, when the url is generated there is a call made to `getDoNotUseCategoryId` that also does not exist.  it is equivalent to `->getData('do_not_use_category_id')`.